# Passing value from one subreport to another

Tags: variables, jasper-reports, global

I have an report with two sub reports. The first sub report has a total that I need use for the second sub report. Is there a way for the sub report to set the parent report parameter or variable or to use a global variable?

Comment: I also have the same question. did you find a method for this ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using iReport 5.0. When I click on the subreport in my main report, in the Properties box under Parameters there is an option for Return Values. Try setting this to be what you want the subreport to pass back to the main report.